# Casting between signed and unsigned

Tags: c++, casting, unsigned, unsafe, signed

Is this safe:

```
int main()
{
    boost::int16_t t1 = 50000; // overflow here.
    boost::uint16_t t2 = (boost::uint16_t)t1;
    std::cout << t1 << " "  << t2 <<  std::endl;
}
```

To be even more specific: I'm storing this data in a table which is using signed types in its schema, is it safe to store, and retrieve this data in this manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code using the `101010` button atop of the edit pane. And no, C-style are never safe. I can say that without even looking at what that cast does.

Comment: @sbi, a signed to unsigned cast (for example) with the same width is safe and completely well-defined, regardless of what syntax you use.

Comment: I agree, using a recast templates with primitive types seems like a ridiculous overkill to me.

Comment: @Matthew, @teukkam: I obviously agree. +1 :).

Comment: @Matthew, @teukkam: It might be safe looking at the code _right now_. But let that code ripe a decade, with a few dozen maintainers changing stuff here and there. Then the C-style cast might __prevent the compiler from indicating a problem__ that had entered during maintenance which it would emit a diagnostic for had you been using a `static_cast`. Oh, and try to __grep your code for C-style casts__. I once had to work with someone who had to find such casts because they would blow due to alignment issues on a new platform a 2MLoC code base needed porting to. Weeks of fun. You live, you learn.

Comment: @sbi: Completely agree on the issues with C-style casts being a headache during maintenance and automated source reviews / analyses.

Comment: @sbi - Do you prefer `static_cast<vector<Foo> >(10).swap(myvec);` to `vector<Foo>(10).swap(myvec);`?

Comment: @Steve: I'm surprised you wouldn't think that this is a very different issue. Explicitly calling a constructor isn't at all like casting between integer types, risking truncation. (Yes, I know about the syntactical details fuzzing the border between those. But that doesn't score a point in my eyes.)

Comment: @sbi: I think that your statement, "I can say without even looking that C-style casts are never safe", is over-broad. I don't think that there is a strict difference between `vector<Foo>(10)` vs. `uint16_t(t1)` vs. `int16_t(50000)` vs `(uint16_t)t1`. The vector has the user-friendly property that different inputs always produce defined behavior and (barring an exception) outputs that are "different" in some sense. So I think you *do* have to look at the cast to know whether it's safe or not.

Comment: Also, if the "danger" of C-style casting integer types is truncation, or warning-suppression, then the static cast is equally "dangerous". You're more along the right lines with use of "grep", and I'd add that the C++-style casts are better in general because they're more specific. Because they do less, forcing you to choose the right one, it's easier to see what they actually do in a given case.

Comment: @Steve: I think that VC, when in `static_cast<T>(X)` the type of the variable `X` changes so that it becomes a narrowing conversion, will warn about that. However, I don't think it warns about `(T)X`. ICBWT.

Comment: @sbi: so if you *want* a narrowing conversion, you have to write code that's harder to search for and re-check later? I've never been convinced by MSVC's warnings, but then I guess MS expects the warning to be manually disabled in the source, rather than worked around by changing the code.

Comment: @Steve: It seems you forgot that my argument was about conversions that _changed_ from "fine-as-is" to "you-should-have-a-look-at-this" during maintenance. (First the code was _not_ raising a flag, then you change it, then the compiler flags a conversion.) If the code was narrowing from the beginning, but was what you wanted nevertheless, you could turn the warning off/change the code/whatever fits your bill right from the beginning. If the warning appears _after_ you changed something, you look at it and _then_ decide what to do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I believe this is implementation defined.  From the C++ draft standard, §4.7/3

> If the destination type is signed, the
>   value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type
>   (and bit-ﬁeld width); otherwise, the
>   value is implementation-deﬁned.

This applies to the first statement.  `int16_t` is signed, and it can not represent 50000.  So the value of `t1` depends on the implementation.

Once you know `t1`, `t2` is guaranteed by §4.7/2 to be the lowest `uint16_t` congruent modulus 2^16 to `t1`.  Basically, `t1` mod 2^16.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's safe, but why not using an uint16_t without going through this misleading cast?

Types exists for communication also, not only for the sake of compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a number that cannot be represented in a signed type is implementation-defined. The next conversion however has a standard defined behaviour. So the outcome of the function is implementation defined, if that is safe or not, is a subjective matter. But portable across platforms or compilers it is not.